# Getting error - This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinsta

Tags: usb, boot

I am sorry if I am repeating this issue. But I am a layman and cant understand the answers posted.

I want to do away with Windows XP Professional (I have lost the product key) that I have on an old desktop PC that is more than 7/8 years old. I didnt use the PC for a couple of years as this laptop was more convenient. Now I have started to use this PC but cannot download SP2 onto the PC as it keeps asking for product key and I dont remember where I wrote it down or where I kept it.

So I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 onto the desktop screen (about 753MB and 3 hours) and then used Unetbootin to put this on my pendrive. After completing the process, I have on my pendrive 9 folders, 3 text files, 1 autorun file, 1 ldlinux file, 1 wubi application file and 5 other files - total 20 items.

Though on bootup I opted for USB boot, the boot-up opens into Windows. It simply bypasses the USB where ubuntu lies.

What do I do? Am I doing things correctly. Pls explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

You computer is probably not configured to start on your USB key when it's powered on. Try the following steps :

- Shutdown completely your computer.
- Plug your USB key.
- Switch on your computer then immediately try to press "F9" key on your keyboard. Depending of your computer manufacturer. If nothing append, try "ESC" key or other "Fx" key (the key is often showed on the first screen image when computer is switched on, try to find something named "boot menu").
- Once in the menu, choose something like "USB key" or "USB hard drive" item.

If you computer is not able to show you a boot menu or doesn't show "USB key", it's probably too old to boot from your USB key, in this case, you will have to burn the ISO file on a empty CD.

Comment: I did ths and pressed F8 key. I then selected USB Micro cruzer and pressed Return. Yet it keeps bypassing USB and goes to IDE (I guess this is hard Drive C: where windows xp is stored). Btw, the RAM is only 256 MB. Is that also a problem for Ubuntu. I tried this USB on my laptop just now and it worked fine. But cant get it to work on old desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: On some other query it is mentioned that to try and install 8.10 release. Will that work?